# How to apply style on QScrollArea?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I'm having problems with QScrollArea style. It doesn't apply the style to the  QScrollBar within it. I  downloaded this CSS from Github.

```
QScrollBar:vertical{
  background:palette(base);
  border-top-right-radius:2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
  width:16px;
  margin:0px;
}
/*...and so on.*/
```

Comment: You can give us more information about the error you get perhaps by showing an image of what you get and what you want to get.

Comment: works for me………